# CSS Android avoid automatic line break after any word

Tags: android, css, popup, line-breaks, word-wrap

I use CSS to display an info window.
This is my code:

```
    /*Popup*/
    .popupheader{
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    color:#fff;
    width: 300px;
    Font-Family:Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size:9pt;
    }

    .popupbody{
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #b5b5b5;
    color:black;
    width: 300px;
    font-family:Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size:9pt;
    }
```

In Firefox no problem but in the Android bowser/webview text line is broken after any word..like:

```
    this
    is
    my
    text
```

The problem happen only in the popupbody not in the popupheader. I try everything like: white-space, overflow-word, word-break but nothing work. Please help.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you ever find a fix for this?